# Silverlight: Can't force update of binding to collection via INPC?

Tags: silverlight

Say I have a `ListBox` that is bound to an observable collection on my view model, where the data item is a simple class that has a `Name` and a `Value` property.

When I add or remove items from the view model collection, the ListBox updates automatically as I would expect.

However, if I change the name of a data item, I want the ListBox to refresh as well, so I raise a property change for the view model property that exposes the observable collection after I've updated the name in code. The ListBox won't update however.

It's as if the binding is saying, well, the object you're giving me (the collection itself) is the same as the last one I had, so it hasn't really changed, has it? Silly programmer, telling me to refresh when I don't need to!

There are only a couple of ways I have found to work around this issue:

- Raise an explicit Reset notification from the collection itself (requires subclassing of ObservableCollection to do this)
- Recreate the list using a new observable collection, then raise the property change - the collection object is different now so the binding updates

Neither of these two ways are ideal, although the first method is definitely preferable - it really shouldn't be this hard to get a listbox to update!

Can anyone explain why bindings work this way, and if there is any way to change the behaviour so that the binding will always update on a property change notification, regardless of whether the source has changed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the items within your `ObservableCollection` do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You need to do this, so that when you change the `Name` property of an item in the collection, the UI is updated. From your description, the framework and your bound collection are working exactly as the should.